# Executing script when email arrives

Tags: thunderbird, email

Is there a way to process email upon arrival. I've tried Mailbox Alert in Thunderbird, the add-in executes the script although as far as I know the message (the content of the email) is not given to the `stdin`.

EDIT: since more info was wanted

I wrote a script, let's call it `script.sh` that can be executed with `/bin/bash`.

The script expects as input the content of the email (text or html), and processes it (for instance performing `grep` on it and storing the results in another file).

Comment: Can this be more explained?  Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to process using a script. Are you interested in CLI program?

Comment: How are the emails being retrieved? Aliases can be used to do exactly what you describe for postfix, but I'm not 100% sure how that works with Thunderbird.

Comment: can you give your script?

Comment: Do you want to process message body ?. Subject, sender, size etc can be passed to the script by thunder bird.

Comment: What protocol are you receiving your mail with? Is it local delivery, POP, IMAP, …?

Answer (score 2):

You can try addon named [FiltaQuilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/filtaquilla/) which in theory allows you to execute an external command during message filtering.

Comment: It's outdated add-on though.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it seems they are working on it again. The latest version is compatible with TB 78.